# Accessing objects stored within arrays stored within objects

Tags: javascript

Data as follows;

```
var graphs = {
    "links": [
        {"source": 1, "target": 2}, 
        {"source": 3, "target": 4}
    ]
}
```

Putting links into a variable called links;

```
var links = graphs.links;
```

How do I then access the source and target values?
Thanks in advance.

re some of the answers given - I think this my problem is context dependent. I tried links[x].source to return source of xth link, however when I try it in my code at a specific point I get an array of objects returned rather than values;

This is the full snippet of code;

```
d3.select("#filterResults")
    .on("click", function() {

        //d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function(d, i) {return i % 2 == 0})
        //  .attr("fill", "green")
        var nodeArray = []
        d3.selectAll("circle[fill=\"Red\"]")
            .each(function(d, i) {
                if (d3.select(this).attr("fill") == "Red") {
                    nodeArray.push(d3.select(this).attr("node-index"))
                }

            })

        nodeArray.forEach(function(srcNode, srcIdx, srcList) {
            alert(srcNode)
        })

        for (i=0; i < links.length; i++) {
        alert(links[i].source)

    })
```

The objective is to identify which nodes the user has clicked (and turned red) and then ultimately I'll create a dataset only of these nodes and update my data selection to show only those. It's kind of a filtering method in the context of d3 force.

So why doesn't iterating through the links work here? I can use links.length and I get the correct number of links so I can reference the array just fine.

Comment: Use bracket notation `links[index].source` or iterate through the array. That's pretty basic question.

Comment: Either directly, like `graphs.links[0].source`, or using a loop.

Comment: Hey down voters, the question is specific and relevant (and with code examples!) - what more do you want?

Answer (score 2):

`links` is array. You can access the array elements via `links[0]`, `links[1]`, etc. Those individual elements are objects, so if you want to access properties on the objects, you can do `links[0].target` or `links[0]['target']`.

Answer (score 1):

`graphs.links`, or just `links` like you have it, is just an array of objects:

```
var firstSource = links[0].source;

// or
var i;
for (i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    console.log("Source #" + i + ": " + links[i].source);
    console.log("Target #" + i + ": " + links[i].target);
}
```

Comment: For completeness's sake, you can also iterate using the `Array.prototype.forEach()` method: `links.forEach(function (item, index) { ... });`.

Comment: Looks like `forEach` is IE9+ only (in addition to real browsers), so I'd be careful using it if you have any chance of users on IE8.

Answer (score 0):

To access source and target, you can use 
`links[0].source` and `links[0].target`

Answer (score 0):

Access the source of the first link:
`var link1 = graphs.links[0].source;`

Access the target of the second link:
`var link2 = graphs.links[1].target;`